# addition in js using json for different values

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, reactjs

I'am trying to do addition in js:

- but i am not getting the right answers.
- i should get the values as 5444.54.
- but i am getting as 4444.541000.
- can you guys tell me how to fix it.
- providing the code below

  console.log("sportsFreeKick--->" + JSON.stringify(data.balance.sportsGoals)); // 1000

  console.log("sportsTime--->" + sportsTime); // 4444.54

  console.log(sportsTime + JSON.stringify(data.balance.sportsGoals)); // 4444.541000

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number/toFixed

Comment: Because you are concating strings, not numbers

Comment: Can you guys update the solution... it's confusing

Comment: `"A" + "B" = "AB"` so `"1" + "2" = "12"` while `1 + 2 = 3` You need to convert the string to a number